# How to use WebPack Encore together with FOSJsRouting?

Tags: webpack-encore, fosjsroutingbundle

I'm trying to integrate WebPack Encore with FOSJsRouting. I don't have a lot of experience with WebPack but I did use FOSJsRouting successfully without it.

I'm following the official documentation and I'm getting this error when Encore runs the build process>

```
"export 'default' (imported as 'Routing') was not found in '../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.js'
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the code you use to import the Routing module please? n the documentation, they import the minified version and your error seems to say you import the not minified one. It could change things.

Answer (score -1):

You can find your answer in the documentation here : https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html

You can reply with a comment if you want more help.

Comment: Thanks @florian. The problem is, I did follow the documentation and got to the error I posted (which I couldn't solve)